# Parameter bounds in matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds

What restrictions apply to the scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in order for
$$
\mathrm{tr}({\bf X}\cdot{\bf X}) 
+ \alpha({\bf v}\cdot{\bf X}\cdot{\bf v})^2
+ \beta({\bf v}\cdot{\bf X}\cdot{\bf X}\cdot{\bf v})
\ge 0
$$
to be fulfilled for any symmetric 3x3 matrix ${\bf X}$ and any *normalized* 3x1 vector ${\bf v}$?

Of course, the $\mathrm{tr}({\bf X}\cdot{\bf X})$ and $({\bf v}\cdot{\bf X}\cdot{\bf v})^2$ are strictly positive, and I suspect that ${\bf v}\cdot{\bf X}\cdot{\bf X}\cdot{\bf v}$ is too.
In this case, it would seem that $\alpha,\beta\ge0$ is sufficient.

However, does a more general relationship exist between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that fulfills the above inequality?

Comment: I suspect you mean $\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}$? In that case, the term $\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}$ is strictly positive for $\mathbf{v}\neq0$ if $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}$ is positive definite (all eigenvalues are positive). -- Edit: This is the case, by the way $\mathbf{v}^\top \mathbf{X}=(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v})^\top$. hence any non-negative $\alpha,\beta$ suffices

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by using the dot notation. Thank you for clarifying that this term is positive. 
I am, however, still interested in a possible (more general) relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ than them being non-negative?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no relationship, except when $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are known (then it becomes quite a trivial problem). This problem also occurs when solving matrix inequalities where some of the terms are confined in a polytopic set. The solvers that I use to solve these problems (e.g. ROLMIP), only aim on finding positive $\alpha, \beta$... However, I'm not an expert, so maybe there is a relationship